# Can't read JSON file using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this json file I try to read using JS but it returns a syntax error: unexpected token at line 2 ":"

Where could this error come from?

```
   fetch('../json/destinations_data.json')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    window.alert(data);
    console.log(data);
  });
```

```
{
    "user1":{
        "email":"lucien.bramare@gmail.com",
        "password":"oss117",
        "prenom":"Lucien",
        "nom":"Bramare"
    },
    "user2":{
        "email":"noel.flantier@gmail.com",
        "password":"oss117",
        "prenom":"Noël",
        "nom":"Flantier"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're parsing it as text, not JSON.

```
   fetch('../json/destinations_data.json')
      .then(response => response.json()) //<-- do this!
      .then(data => {
          window.alert(data);
          console.log(data);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse it as **json** and not as **text**

replace this

```
  .then(response => response.text())
```

with this

```
  .then(response => response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading json file so instead of using `response.text()` use `response.json()`

```
   fetch('../json/destinations_data.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    window.alert(data);
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your json file. You have to change your format. Please check https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

```
users = [
    {
       "email":"lucien.bramare@gmail.com",
       "password":"oss117",
       "prenom":"Lucien",
       "nom":"Bramare"
   },
   {
       "email":"noel.flantier@gmail.com",
       "password":"oss117",
       "prenom":"Noël",
       "nom":"Flantier"
    }
];
```